# Как сделать data-driven юнит-тесты?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit

Тестирую веб-сайт с использованием Selenium Webdriver (Firefox) и JUnit. В данный момент разные тест-кейсы работают с одним набором данных. Хочу разделить данные и реализацию, чтобы запускать одни и те же сценарии с разными данными.

Пока что данные инциализируются в `@Before`, но я могу выделить их хоть в XML, хоть в Properties. С этим затруднений нет.

В чем проблема: не представляю, **как заставить юнит-тесты запускаться многократно, используя различные данные?**

Я мог бы легко это сделать, отказавшись от использования JUnit. Просто вручную запускать методы и вручную же перебирать и скармливать им данные. Но это страшный велосипед и я не хочу терять преимуществ JUnit (таких, например, как автозапуск через Maven, красивое логирование, легкий запуск одного метода из тест-комплекта либо всего комплекта и т.д).

```
public class TestSuite {
    /**
     * Входные данные — строки и числа 
     * */
    String searchString;
    String firmID;
    String geoID;

    private DGDriver driver; //extends FirefoxDriver

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new DGDriver(); 
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        /** Сейчас данные инициализируются так */
        searchString = "главный вокзал";
        firmID = "141265769369926";
        geoID = "141373143526113";

    }

    @Test
    public void testCase1 {

        /* Тут вызываются методы, использующие данные.
        Думаю, по именам понятно, как они их используют */

        driver.homepage();
        driver.searchFor(searchString);
        driver.searchResults.clickItem(firmID);
        driver.firmCard.clickAddress();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Если вам недостаточно вышеприведенного кода, я могу разве что дать ссылку на репозиторий, т.к. `DGDriver` крупноват для вопроса на SO.

Comment: вроде решаемо через https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests

Comment: https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams/wiki/Quickstart очень похоже на data providers в PHPUnit, гораздо удобней parametrized

Comment: @Etki: ха, "Parameterised tests that don't suck". Спасибо, попробую их.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решил следующим образом:

В JUnit есть аннотации [@Parametrized](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests)

```
/**
 * Обязательна вот такая аннотация класса:
 */
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class LeafletMarkerTests {


    /**
     * значение аннотации value указывает на номер параметра в массиве
     */
    @Parameterized.Parameter(0)
    public String searchString;

    @Parameterized.Parameter(1)
    public String firmID;

    @Parameterized.Parameter(2)
    public String geoID;

    @Parameterized.Parameter(3)
    public int expectedTransformX;
    @Parameterized.Parameter(4)
    public int expectedTransformY;
    @Parameterized.Parameter(5)
    public int expectedTransformZ;
    Vector3d expectedCzarTransform;

    // разные другие переменные

    /**
     * можно задать названия датасетов, чтобы было понятнее, на каком тест зафейлился
     */
    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{index}: {0}")
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                /*{searchString, firmID, geoID, x, y, z}*/
                {"главный вокзал", "141265769369926", "141373143526113", 767, 289, 0},
                {"цирк", "141265769338191", "141373143518884", 935, 289, 0},
                {"оперный", "141265769360673", "141373143521691", 767, 289, 0},
                {"старый дом", "141265769360664", "141373143532548", 767, 289, 0},
                {"сансити", "141265770417218", "141373143572328", 767, 289, 0},
        });
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new DGDriver(); //extends FirefoxDriver
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Инициализация этих параметров в @Before уже не нужна
    }

    public void test1() {...}

    ...
}
```

Так запущенный параметризованный тест-комплект выглядит в IntelliJ IDEA CE:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Нашел [специализированное решение для data-driven тестов на JUnit](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/08/writing-data-driven-tests-for-your-java-application.html).