# Тестирование ветвления в Java c помощью JUnit

Tags: java, junit

Есть метод, к которому необходимо написать unit-тест, в котором будет учтено четыре возможных значение newByte(-1, 0, 1, и другое любое число).

Так как для компилятора строка остается не покрытой тестом

```
if ((newByte == 0) || (newByte == 1) || (newByte == -1))
```

Сам метод:

```
public static byte primConvertToByte(final byte changeByte) {
    // byte values [-128, 127]
    byte newByte = changeByte;
    // error values: -1, 0, 1 because of involution changeInt.Solve for adding TWO.
    if ((newByte == 0) || (newByte == 1) || (newByte == -1)) {
        newByte += (byte) PrimitiveConvensionRunner.TWO;
    }
    newByte *= PrimitiveConvensionRunner.TWO;

    return newByte;
}
```

Вот пример моего теста, который нужно корректно исправить под эти значения (у меня учитывается только одно).

```
@Test
public void testPrimConvertToByte() {
    final byte startValue = 1;
    final byte expectedByteValueFirst = 6;
    new PrimitiveConvensionRunner();
    Assert.assertEquals("Test for Byte", expectedByteValueFirst,
            PrimitiveConvensionRunner.primConvertToByte(startValue));

}
```

Comment: и что мешает попробовать написать еще три assert-а для оставшихся трех значений?

Comment: @Nofate При таком способе для компилятора строка кода (newByte == 0) || (newByte == 1) || (newByte == -1) остаётся не покрытой (2 of 3 branches are missed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На каждый случай — отдельный тест. В данном методе есть пять групп эквивалентности: меньше -1, -1, 0, 1, больше 1. На каждую должен быть отдельный тест в общем тест-комплекте.

**Вариант простой, но нарушающий DRY:**

```
public void testPrimConvertToByte(byte startValue, byte expected, string message) {
    new PrimitiveConvensionRunner();
    Assert.assertEquals(message, expected,
            PrimitiveConvensionRunner.primConvertToByte(startValue));
}

@Test
public void testPrimConvertToByteNegative()
{
    testPrimConvertToByte(1, 6, "should return 6 for argument equal to 1");
}

@Test
public void testPrimConvertToByteMinusOne()
{
    testPrimConvertToByte(-1, 100500, "should return 100500 for argument equal to -1");
}

@Test
public void testPrimConvertToByteOne()
{
    testPrimConvertToByte(42, 1337, "should return leet value for argument more than 1");
}

...
```

**Вариант посложнее, но лаконичный:**

Написать [data-driven](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/445963/181472) тесты.